# run a task on ui thread from fragment

Tags: java, android, multithreading

how to run a task on ui thread. I am trying to run a task on ui thread

```
  MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                        "Mytask finished", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i found the solution for running task on ui thread in the fragment activity
just change the MainActivity.this to getActivity() that will fix the error.
i think this might help.

```
Thread timer = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
//do something
     getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Token Generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
       }
            };
            timer.start();
```

Comment: check this out   http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: sir i have searched it. i was working on something and couldnt find the answer. so thought i should share it.

Comment: @Metehan It is perfectly acceptable to ask a question and then answer it yourself.